# Python feature selection

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, feature-selection

I have an error while performing Feature Selection in Python. I am new to python.
Problem :

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
array = df.values
X = array[:,0:49]
Y = array[:,48]
# feature extraction
model = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 20)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
print("Num Features: %d") % fit.n_features_
print("Selected Features: %s") % fit.support_
print("Feature Ranking: %s") % fit.ranking_
```

when I run this code, it shows an error

```
ValueError: could not convert the string to float: 'High Prone'
```

My target variable in df is 'High Prone' and 'Less prone'.
I have done factorizing but it doesn't work.

Comment: can you please paste your dataframe here.

Comment: looks like your dataframe is having 'NaN' values which is creating this issue.

Comment: I have no NaN values. and how can i paste my dataframe

Comment: Just give us a toy sample of how your dataframe looks like

Answer (score 0):

You probably need [sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to encode your target variable to numerical values.

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_encoded = le.fit_transform(y)
fit = rte.fit(X, y_encoded)
```

Comment: I have used your code but its not working yet. I have pasted it after Y array line.

Comment: Do `y_encoded = le.fit_transform(y)` and use `y_encoded` instead of `y` for the fit.

Comment: It would be a good idea to update your post with this, and not put code & verbal instructions in the comments...